# Switching poster from A0 landscape to A1 portrait

Tags: posters

I use a poster template with a A0 landscape format. I am using a template from `overleaf`. the set up of the poster is as follow:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usetheme{EastLansing}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption} 
\usetheme{confposter} 
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10}
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usetheme{EastLansing}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usetheme{confposter} 
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10}
```

I tried few options to change the format of this poster from A0 landscape to A1 portrait. But each time it's just ruining the all layout of the poster. Does anyone know how to easily reformat the layout of the poster?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Your code looks really strange as you seem  load several time all the packages and class. 
And xhat to you want to do ?

Comment: @samcarter - I will try to do it now. Maybe if you have an idea I can share with you my overleaf template? (https://www.overleaf.com/read/fstcsrnyqcbk)